# Apache POI - How to copy tables from one docx to another docx

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi I am trying to copy a table from a docx file to another but what happens is that the value of the table are copied down bellow the table in the new document and outside of it (see pictures bellow)

Table in original docx
[image]

Talbe in the new docx

[image]

As you can see the values of the table are copied outside the table.
I am using Libre Office, apache poi version 3.17 and my computer runs Ubuntu 16.04

The code I am using to perform the copy is the following

```
public static void copyTable(XWPFDocument input_doc,XWPFDocument output_doc,
                             int table_index_input, int table_index_output) {

    XWPFTable template_table = input_doc.getTables().get(table_index_input);

    CTTbl ctTbl = CTTbl.Factory.newInstance(); // Create a new CTTbl for the new table
    ctTbl.set(template_table.getCTTbl()); // Copy the template table's CTTbl
    XWPFTable new_table = new XWPFTable(ctTbl, output_doc); // Create a new table using the CTTbl upon

    output_doc.createParagraph();
    output_doc.createTable();// Create a empty table in the document
    output_doc.setTable(table_index_output, new_table);  // Replace the empty table to table2

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
XWPFTable newTbl = output_doc.insertNewTbl(cursor);
copyTable(table, newTbl);
```

and the copyTable() method

```
private void copyTable(XWPFTable source, XWPFTable target) {
    target.getCTTbl().setTblPr(source.getCTTbl().getTblPr());
    target.getCTTbl().setTblGrid(source.getCTTbl().getTblGrid());
    for (int r = 0; r<source.getRows().size(); r++) {
        XWPFTableRow targetRow = target.createRow();
        XWPFTableRow row = source.getRows().get(r);
        targetRow.getCtRow().setTrPr(row.getCtRow().getTrPr());
        for (int c=0; c<row.getTableCells().size(); c++) {
            //newly created row has 1 cell
            XWPFTableCell targetCell = c==0 ? targetRow.getTableCells().get(0) : targetRow.createCell();
            XWPFTableCell cell = row.getTableCells().get(c);
            targetCell.getCTTc().setTcPr(cell.getCTTc().getTcPr());
            XmlCursor cursor = targetCell.getParagraphArray(0).getCTP().newCursor();
            for (int p = 0; p < cell.getBodyElements().size(); p++) {
                IBodyElement elem = cell.getBodyElements().get(p);
                if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                    XWPFParagraph targetPar = targetCell.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
                    cursor.toNextToken();
                    XWPFParagraph par = (XWPFParagraph) elem;
                    copyParagraph(par, targetPar);
                } else if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
                    XWPFTable targetTable = targetCell.insertNewTbl(cursor);
                    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable) elem;
                    copyTable(table, targetTable);
                    cursor.toNextToken();
                }
            }
            //newly created cell has one default paragraph we need to remove
            targetCell.removeParagraph(targetCell.getParagraphs().size()-1);
        }
    }
    //newly created table has one row by default. we need to remove the default row.
    target.removeRow(0);
}
```

the copyParagraph()

```
private void copyParagraph(XWPFParagraph source, XWPFParagraph target) {
    target.getCTP().setPPr(source.getCTP().getPPr());
    for (int i=0; i<source.getRuns().size(); i++ ) {
        XWPFRun run = source.getRuns().get(i);
        XWPFRun targetRun = target.createRun();
        //copy formatting
        targetRun.getCTR().setRPr(run.getCTR().getRPr());
        //no images just copy text
        targetRun.setText(run.getText(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I have some questions (1) what is the parameter cursor you are passing to function call insertNewTbl (2) what imports do i need for all of these to work ( for XmlCursor for instance) and (3) can you provide me with a little info about the all XmlCursos stuff you are using ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also what is the method insertNewTbl you are reffering to in your answer and what is the second argument you are passing to it

Comment: All the things are already in the POI lib. Cursor is a ... how to say ... pointer where some action could be applied. If you need to create a table in the mid fo content... e.g. after the third paragraph in the document. But in our case cursor to the target cell first paragraph

Comment: Great code. Any chance that Word checkboxes inside cells could also be copied?

Comment: @golimar Have not tried checkboxes. Need to investigate and copy some additional attributes

Comment: @StanislavL The value can be read from the paragraph with getIRuns(), but there seems to be no create/set/insert method for IRuns

Comment: The `copyParagraph()` above copies the paragraph text only. If there is a picture in any of the runs, then it is not copied. My version:

```java

void copyParagraph(final XWPFParagraph source, final XWPFParagraph target) {
            target.getCTP().set(source.getCTP().copy());
            target.getCTP().getRList().clear();
            for (final var run : source.getRuns()) {
                final var r = target.getCTP().addNewR();
                r.set(run.getCTR());
                target.addRun(new XWPFRun(r, (IRunBody) target));
            }
        }

```

Comment: @StanislavL

Your copy table needs some modification to copy tables that have tables inside. When you create a new table with `insertNewTbl()` there are no rows in the table and the last `removeRow()` removes the first row of the table. This also orphans the paragraphs that may be in the cells in the first row causing different exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think easier and more reliable form of copyTable function would be something like this.

```
private void copyTable(XWPFTable source, XWPFTable target) {
        CTTbl sourceCTTbl = source.getCTTbl();
        CTTbl targetCTTbl = target.getCTTbl();
        targetCTTbl.setTblPr(sourceCTTbl.getTblPr());
        targetCTTbl.setTrArray(sourceCTTbl.getTrArray());
}
```

(It works for me at least)

Comment: Your version works if you do not want to use the table further in your processing. In my case, my code manipulates the table after it was copied (included from the other file), resolving Jamal macros in the cells. Your version does not work in this case because the POI objects are not copied, only the underlying XML objects, AFAIK. However, the more complex above does work.

Comment: @PeterVerhas thank you for comment, I remember that I have some issues with complicated answer, because it didn't copy pictures from the table or something like that

Comment: Perfect @MarcinBelicki, it works wonderfully for me!